# How to show docker logs until container becomes healthy

Tags: linux, docker, logging, gitlab, queue

I'm trying to create CI infrastructure for a project. We deploy application with docker. It usually takes some time, to start up application. I would like to see in my gitlab job logs my docker logs.... but I would like stop displaying them as soon as application will start returning `200` on selected endpoint.

I already have a healthcheck configured for my containers in docker-compose file if that would be helpful.

I would like to avoid checking health check status manually and displaying parts of logs with `docker-compose logs --tail`, because then I could get duplicated lines. So maybe I should use some kind of queue file?

Do you maybe know any tools which could simplify this?

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. :)